# date filtering of first day of the previous month and last day of the previous month impala

Tags: impala

I have impala query to select records from table. but I need to filter the records from first day of the previous month and last day of the previous month.which means current month feb, but I need to get records only between 1 Jan and 31 jan.

Thank you all

Answer (score 2):

This can be done using impala's [date functions](https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-11-x/topics/impala_datetime_functions.html). For example, getting the first day of the previous month can be done by calculating the first of this month and then subtracting one month:

`months_sub(date_sub(load_date,  dayofmonth(load_date)-1), 1)`

Calculating the end of the month can be done in a similar way.

Comment: Thanks for the response